# Usage reporting for WSS 3.0

Tags: wss-3.0, reports, usage-counters, site-usage

I want to rollup statistics on site usage, but all I have is WSS 3.0. This will be a one-time task, so I don't want over-think it too much. I am currently collecting usage data. Is that information available to powershell or is there a published schema where I can retrieve it? If I can get it out, I can use any reporting tool.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get usage data from the [WSS 3.0 Usage Event Logs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb814929%28v=office.12%29.aspx) aggregated from thousands of site collections using Microsoft’s [Log Parser 2.2 tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659).   Because the WSS 3.0 Usage Event Log file format is not an out of the box supported input format for Log Parser 2.2, I had to code a custom input format plug-in.

Below are some useful resources I used in my journey to analyzing usage data.

**Log Parser 2.2**

- [How Log Parser 2.2 Works](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb878032.aspx)
- Jeff Atwood has a nice [post on Microsoft LogParser](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html)

**Custom Input Format Plugin**

- I wrote the plug-in in C#. The sample code provided with the Log Parser 2.2 installation was helpful, located at Log Parser 2.2\Samples\COM\BooksXML
- [This stackoverflow post was helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/182361/1189774), in particular the answer provided by @Nico.
- The key for me was in reading the a record using the ReadRecord() method. I wrote my own ReadRecord() method using the steps below:

  1. Read each field in the record’s header entry (Examining the Usage Log File Format was very helpful)
  2. Using the values (which indicate the length in bytes for a given field) from the header entry, I read the respective number of characters for that field.

Finally, I was able to run LogParser 2.2 using the custom input format plug-in and output the results to a SQL Server database table.