# Site usage report from Database

Tags: 2007, database, view, site-usage

I have a SP 2007 site where site usage is enabled and I can check the usage for last thirty days. I wanted the usage details for last 6 months for which I went to SharePoint Designer but my SPD is crashing again and again for this site. I updated it to SP3 with no luck. Can anyone please tell me how to get these reports from DB. I know there are views which can get me such data. I tried with

```
ANLHitsByResourceByDay
ANLHitsByResourceByUserByDay
ANLSiteResourceHits
```

But I need to joining it for correct data. I want the hit of index.html file located in one specific document library. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In researching for a similar problem, I've come across two different ways to get usage data from the MOSS 2007 Shared Services Database (db where the ANL* tables are located). They both query the database but in different ways:

- The [SharePoint is not enough blog](http://dkolitha.wordpress.com/2008/02/13/sharepoint-2007-usage-reports/) provides a sample query against the 'ANL' tables on how to view the most popular documents in a SharePoint site.
- Karla Ponce's SharePoint with Attitude [Getting more than 30 Days of SharePoint Usage Report Data](http://www.sharepointwithattitude.com/archives/41) blog post shows how to query the Shared Services Database using the SharePoint object model. From the post: 
  "PortalContext object contains a reference to the Shared Services Database through the property “AnalyticsSqlSession.” She provides an example of how to setup a read-only query against the usage tables.

In my situation, I am working with WSS 3.0 and there is no Shared Service database. So I am getting the needed usage information from the Usage Event Logs.

Comment: I described how I was able to get WSS 3.0 usage data from the Usage Event Logs in [another sharepoint.stackexchange answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/49794/9098).